# check whether a checkbox is checked or nt using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this code for checking the checkbox is selected or not and disabling other checkboxes on that basis but it is always reading false irrespective of checkbox is selected or not .

```
<script>
    function DisableCheckboxes(id) {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
        if (!isChecked) {
               document.getElementById("test1").disabled = false;
               document.getElementsByClassName("EducationCheckbox2001").disabled = false;

            } else {
               document.getElementById("test1").disabled = true;
               document.getElementsByClassName("EducationCheckbox2001").disabled = true;
            }
    }

</script>
```

i am not getting whats wrong can anyone help me.

Comment: Side note: You should decide which way to go. `jQuery` or `Vanilla Javascript`. There's no reason to mix them up here.

Comment: Show us your `HTML` markup.

Comment: how is `DisableCheckboxes` called? what is `id`?

Comment: i just want to go with but what's wrong i am doing in it ,i am not getting it.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="2011" class="EducationCheckbox2011" value="EducationLiteracyRate2011" id="test" onclick="DisableCheckboxes(test)" ><br> this is way i am calling it

Comment: id is the id of checkbox

Comment: where is your `test1` id which you used in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `getElementsByClassName` has a problem since it returns an array, `document.getElementsByClassName("EducationCheckbox2001").disabled` won't do anything. Also you are passing `test` as a variable which also will fail since there are no variable named `test`, you should have passed it as a string like `onclick="DisableCheckboxes('test')"`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="2011" class="EducationCheckbox2011" value="EducationLiteracyRate2011" id="test" onclick="DisableCheckboxes(this)" />
```

then

```
function DisableCheckboxes(el) {
    $('#test1, .EducationCheckbox2001').prop('disabled', el.checked)
}
```

I would also suggest you to move the event registration to jQuery instead of using inlined event handlers, So

```
<input type="checkbox" name="2011" class="EducationCheckbox2011" value="EducationLiteracyRate2011" id="test" />
```

then

```
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function ($) {
    //register a change event handler for the div
    $('#test').change(function (e) {
        $('#test1, .EducationCheckbox2001').prop('disabled', this.checked)
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass your `id` name in single quote like

```
onclick="DisableCheckboxes('test')"
```

You are mixup `javascript` and `jQuery` code. Here `jQuery` code which you want to `enabled/disabled` your checkbox. Try this

```
function DisableCheckboxes(id) 
{
    var isChecked = $("#"+id).is(':checked');        
    $("#test1, .EducationCheckbox2001").prop("disabled",isChecked);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code but it is not working. it is throwinh some error while i debugging it Error is:  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: Try this `onclick="DisableCheckboxes('test')"` in single quote which I mentioined in my answer

Comment: You recommended the OP to stick to `jQuery` but you're not attaching the `event` handler using it. Why keep the inline `Javascript` in the markup?